# Load page that will return that the address was not found. (basically load an non-loadable page)

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Okay, my title is probably not describing especially much, however, here's my PHP code:

```
<h1>404 Server Error</h1>
<?php
$ip = $_GET['ip'];
if($ip) {
$ip = str_replace('%3A', ':', $ip);
$ip = "http://" . $ip;
for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
$ch = curl_init($ip); // (Also tried file_get_contents($ip); instead, but didn't work
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
}
?>
```

I basically want it to load a page that will look something like:
http://123.456.789:80/
(which if you go to the actual site, it will return that the server/site was not found)
But it still gets through the message (I've tried so I know this)

Anyway, CURL nor file_get_contents will work for this as they expect something in return and just keeps running for ages, as they try find the page. But I want them to send a request to the page, then cancel, how would I do this?

TLDR: I want to make the php script send a request/load a page for just a millisecond/second even if it can't load the actual page.

Thanks in advance.

TEMPSOLUTION: I'm using `<iframe src='" . $ip . "'></iframe>` as a temp-solution.

Answer (score 0):

to load a website with php use:

```
header('Location: www.yourwebsite.com');
```

Comment: I want to load it multiple times and within a few seconds, preferrably. I made an temp-solution, editing it in OP.